# Trying to merge 3 vector strings using multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, thread-safety, clion

Basically the goal is to take 4 different text files that contains strings. Merge them into a single vector string list using single-threading and multi-threading, and performing sorting operations on both to calculate the speed. my single-threading logic and sorting algorithms work perfectly fine. the issue is multi-threading. only 3 out of the 4 txt files are merging and sort. The 4th file, which contains the most strings out of all the txt file doesn't merge into the vector list. not sure where i am going wrong.

Heres the code:

```
void MultiThreaded(vector<string> filefist, ESort sort) {
    vector<string> stringlist;
    vector<thread> workerThreads(filelist.size());
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < filelist.size() ; ++i) {
        workerThreads[i] = thread(FileRead, filelist[i],&stringlist);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < filelist.size(); i++){
        workerThreads[i].join();
    }


    stringlist = Sort(stringlist, sort);
}
```

Here's the read file code:

```
void FileRead(string fname, vector<string>* outlist) {
    *outlist = ReadFile(fname);
}
```

The sorting code is the same for both single-threading and multi-threading methods

Comment: when you need help with a bug in your code you need to show the code. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: This is very close to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75961097/). Why did you create a new account to post this question? That kind of action tends to get people banned. If you had an issue with what was told to you earlier, you should have added comments/edits to that post instead.

Answer (score 1):

This code suffers from the same concurrency issue that I pointed out in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75961125/65863) to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75961097/).

You have multiple threads writing to the same `std::vector` *without* adequate synchronization between them. So that will invoke *undefined behavior* if 2 or more threads write to the `std::vector` at the *exact* same moment. `std::vector` is not thread-safe, so you must protect it with a `std::mutex` or equivalent synchronization object.

Even worse, each thread is *replacing* the `std::vector`'s current content with new data, rather than *appending* the new data to it.  So, at best, you will end up with data from only 1 thread, and at worse you will end up with bits and pieces of data from some threads and not others (if you don't just crash outright, or corrupt memory, due to your lack of protection of the `std::vector`).

Try something more like this instead:

```
void FileRead(const std::string& fname, std::vector<std::string>& outlist, std::mutex& mut) {
    std::vector<std::string> data = ReadFile(fname);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
    outlist.insert(outlist.end(), data.begin(), data.end());
}

void MultiThreaded(const std::vector<std::string>& filelist, ESort sort) {
    std::vector<std::string> stringlist;
    std::mutex stringlistMutex;

    std::vector<std::thread> workerThreads;
    workerThreads.reserve(filelist.size());

    for (const auto &file : filelist) {
        workerThreads.emplace_back(FileRead, file, std::ref(stringlist), std::ref(stringlistMutex));
    }

    for (auto &thrd : workerThreads){
        thrd.join();
    }

    stringlist = Sort(stringlist, sort);
}
```

---

On a side note, `Sort()` is returning a new `std::vector`, which you are then assigning back to the `std::vector` that you wanted to be sorted. You should consider changing that design to have `Sort()` directly modify its input `std::vector` inlined instead.  No need for making unnecessary copies.